# Autocomplete order Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, autocomplete, sql-order-by

Is there any way to change the order by of the autocomplete functionality for Visual Studio 2010?

I want to see the autocomplete options ordered by type, I mean:

1. Methods
2. Variables
3. etc...

I dont wan't to get it ordered alphabetically, so what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Assist X allows you to filter by type.
There is a free add on [CSharpIntellisensePresenter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c3eaa4fc-f2de-43ad-92ee-f0f257b79005?SRC=VSIDE)